# Snapshot repldata\unc not clearing

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication

**SQL Server 2008 R2 Snapshot Replication**
***Background Info***
x3 Servers all running MSSQL 2008 R2, on Windows Server 2012:
SERV1 containing two published databases- S1DB1 and S1DB2
SERV2 containing two subscription databases- S2DB1 and S2DB2
SERV3 containing one subscription database- S3DB1

x2 Publications identical in setup:
PUB1 & PUB2

***Set up***
Snapshots are taken of both S1DB1 (PUB1) and S1DB2 (PUB2) daily running on a schedule (all subscriptions are push subscriptions)

PUB1 replicates to S2DB1 daily running on a schedule
PUB1 replicates to S3DB1 on demand (no schedule)
PUB2 replicates to S2DB2 daily running on a schedule

The folder for storing the snapshots is the default folder (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\repldata\unc)

SERV1 _ S1DB1 _ PUB1 I will refer to as FOLD1
SERV1 _ S1DB2 _ PUB2 I will refer to as FOLD2

***Issue***
The sub-folders containing the snapshot data in FOLD2 are being automatically deleted daily, there is only ever one sub-folder in there which is the most recent snapshot. Today for instance there is one sub-folder: "20141104060001".

The sub-folders containing the snapshot data in FOLD1 are *not* being automatically deleted daily, they stack up until they are manually deleted. Today for instance there are three sub-folders: "20141102010002", "20141103010002", and "20141104010002".

This is despite the maximum distribution retention being set at 72-hours but the fact that the sub-folders are usually deleted daily isn't an issue for us, in fact it's more of a help.

I have a hunch that this may be due to the subscription of S3DB1 only being on demand rather than on a schedule, so it's keeping the files so they can be synchronized when needed. Admittedly I haven't yet deleted the subscription for S3DB1 to see if that confirms my theory, but when the subscription is run, the sub-folders still do not clear. If they did, this wouldn't be an issue as we could ensure that we run the subscription every few days to avoid space filling up.

The "Distribution clean up: distribution" job runs fine, and does display
    `"Removed 0 replicated transactions consisting of 0 statements in 0 seconds (0 rows/sec). [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 21010).  The step succeeded."`
as the message, but I haven't yet been able to catch it early enough following a successfully synchronized subscription.

I have at some point deleted PUB1 and all associated subscriptions, and re-created but this was clearly unsuccessful.

Can anyone confirm if I'm on the right track with this? If I am, does anyone know of anyway to ensure this set up can remain in place but with FOLD1 only keeping the most recent snapshot? We only ever use the most recent. So even if there is an sp that can be run to *tell* the SQL Server that all subscriptions have been synchronized (even though they haven't), resulting in it leaving only the most recent snapshot data in FOLD1?

If anyone needs any more info, please do let me know.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide,
Shane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved. It appeared that that the errant publication was also being replicated on a schedule to a third server. The third server (months and months ago) would hang after a day or two, and required a reboot every evening to avoid memory issues.

There were external companies pulling data from this server, which had since ceased, but the replication was not stopped. As the server wasn't being used, it was not being rebooted. Since removing the subscription linked to that server, the historical data has been deleted automatically, only leaving the most recent snapshot.

To 'translate' into my format from the OP:

x3 Servers all running MSSQL 2008 R2, on Windows Server 2012:
SERV1 containing two published databases- S1DB1 and S1DB2
SERV2 containing two subscription databases- S2DB1 and S2DB2
SERV3 containing one subscription database- S3DB1

**x1 Server running MSSQL 2008 R2, on Windows Server 2008 R2:

SERV4 containing one subscription database- S4DB1**

x2 Publications identical in setup:
PUB1 & PUB2

PUB1 replicates to S2DB1 daily running on a schedule
PUB1 replicates to S3DB1 on demand (no schedule)
**PUB1 replicates to S4DB1 daily running on a schedule**
PUB2 replicates to S2DB2 daily running on a schedule